# SQL Server named instance remote connections without port

Tags: sql-server

I have a named instance of SQL Server Express that I want to make it visible on the network. I was able to do it, but other machines can only connect to it specifying the port number, even though it is the default port.

For example, other machines can connect to mine using (1433 is the default port for SQL Server):

```
<hostname>\<instancename>,1433
```

But other machines can't connect without using the port:

```
<hostname>\<instancename>
```

I checked the Firewall (other people can connect specifying the door), and SQL Server Browser is running (I don't fully understand but I read that it make some difference).

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: how other machines are trying to connect?

Comment: Did you restart the SQL Server service after starting the Browser service. This is required.

Comment: FYI The SQL Browser is like a phone book publishing your SQL Server instances to the network. It runs on port 1434. It's typically only required if you use a named instance and want machines outside your network to discover what instances are installed - as well as how to connect to them. If the Browser isn't running, or not accessible, then more specific connection info is required in the connection string, i.e. port number.

Comment: On the other hand, for security reasons, I always keep SQL Browser turned off, set up the instance's TCP/IP to a fixed non-standard port number, and always use that port number when clients connect in.

Comment: IlyaBursov Using SSMS in another machine. BrianKnight Yes, restartes, including SQL Browser. Jerry Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running on the default port try connecting to the host name without the instance name attached.

Answer (score 1):

If you have named instances and don't want to declare your ports then you need to ensure that SQL Server Browser is running. go and check "sql server configuration manager"

Comment: I installed an instance on an old Win-7 laptop in addition to the default SQLServer.  The SQL Server Browser service was set to disabled.  Enabled it and things started working!  Note, I also has to enable TCP\IP Protocol for both instances using Sql Server Configuration Manager.  The default was just Shared Memory set to enabled.